# Работа с одинаковыми классами в JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, классы, double

Всем привет. Сама суть я думаю понятна из заголовка. Не получается реализовать следующую задачу:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".btn").on('click', function() {
    $('.er').each(function(index, element) {
      $(this).find('.qwerty').slideToggle();
    });
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" class="btn" value="Open № 1" />
<div class="er">
  <div class="qwerty">
    <div class="uiop">Тут инфа № 1</div>
  </div>
</div>


<input type="button" class="w" value="Open № 2" />
<div class="er">
  <div class="qwerty">
    <div class="uiop">Тут инфа № 2</div>
  </div>
</div>


<input type="button" class="w" value="Open № 3" />
<div class="er">
  <div class="qwerty">
    <div class="uiop">Тут инфа № 3</div>
  </div>
</div>

<input type="button" class="w" value="Open № 4" />
<div class="er">
  <div class="qwerty">
    <div class="uiop">Тут инфа № 4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

По нажатию на кнопку мне нужно что бы открывался див `.er` находящийся рядом с этой кнопкой. Подскажите где я ошибся пожалуйста. Спасибо заранее.

Comment: дак вы же обращаетесь ко всем `.er`, вот они все и открываются. Или ошибка в другом чем то имеется в виду?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$(".btn").on('click', function() {
  $(this).next('.er').find('.qwerty').slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: При таком коде работает только одна кнопка -- самая первая, ну и соответственно дивы тоже только первые. При нажатии на остальные ничего не происходит

Comment: @sergei1094 у вас класс `.btn` есть только у первой кнопки, у остальных класс `.w`, а надо чтобы у всех кнопок был класс `.btn`.

Comment: @Sasha Omelchenko, спасибо дружище!) Помог. Да и я из-за множества экспериментов вообще не заметил что у меня input'ы с разным классом. Ещё раз спасибо

Comment: @sergei1094 пожалуйста и не забудьте принять этот ответ )

Comment: @Sasha Omelchenko, а ещё вот такой вопросик по этой же теме. А что если кнопка у меня находится далеко.. ДО САМОГО списка Toggle? Как использовать next() в этом случае? Например...<input class=in type=btm /><div></div>......<div></div>......<div></div>.....<div></div> <div class=show>А вот только тут надо этот список показать</div>

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).parent().next('.qwe').find('.commentBlock').slideToggle();
```

Вот то что было мне нужно :)